# MongoDB dataSize command error "couldn't find valid index containing key pattern"

Tags: mongodb

We have two MongoDB clusters, they do not interact with each other. We used to run dataSize command (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dataSize/) to record the storage used for each specified ID. Both two clusters were running smoothly. Recently, we had one cluster's secondary server failure, and we restarted this cluster.  Since then, the dataSize command has stopped working for this cluster. It responds back "couldn't find valid index containing key pattern" error.

Example of the error returned:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.runCommand({ dataSize: "dudubots.channel_tdata", keyPattern: { "c_id_s": 1 }, min: { "c_id_s": 1 }, max: { "c_id_s": 4226 } });
{
    "estimate" : false,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't find valid index containing key pattern",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1553510158, 20),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1553510158, 20),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

The other cluster is running smoothly and no error is given:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.runCommand({ dataSize: "dudubots.channel_tdata", keyPattern: { "c_id_s": 1 }, min: { "c_id_s": 3015 }, max: { "c_id_s": 3017 } })
{
    "estimate" : false,
    "size" : 6075684,
    "numObjects" : 3778,
    "millis" : 1315,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

field **c_id_s** is indeed set as indexes on both clusters. We don't understand why that cluster has failed to run the command.

Comment: Well the dataSize command disagrees with you and thinks you don't have an index. When you say "clusters", please define what you acually mean. Are these shards? Or is this just a totally unrelated replica set to the other one? Note also that you are asking here because you are writing code for an application which performs adminstrative tasks. Nod yes! Because if you were just asking an administrative question for your own database, you should be asking on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. Show proof that you actually have indexes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the problem. The index actually was changed. dataSize command requires index to be ASC, but we had changed one cluster to DSC.